# Definition of a binomial trial

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I would like to give a precise definition of a binomial trial. Is the following a strict and correct definition of a binomial trial?

A binomial trial is n repetitions of the same basic trial, where

1. The basic trial has two outcomes, namely "success" with probability p and "failure" with probability 1-p.
2. The basic trials are independent of each other. In other words, p does not change during the n repetitions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Saying that the trials are independent of each other is not the same as saying that $p$ doesn't change between trials.  You could have independent coin tosses where every coin had a different bias. And you could have dependent trials where all the individual probabilities were the same.

Comment: ".. independent of each other. In other words, $p$ does not change ..." is an incorrect link. $p$ not changing means they are identically distributed, not that they are independent.  You want both.  You also want to say that it is the number of successes which is binomially distributed

Comment: See [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. Is this better.

A stochastic experiment where

1. we consider n basic trials (the important thing is a fixed number).
2. the base trials are independent (i.e. the outcomes of each base trial have no influence on each other).
3. the probability of success is the same in each base trial, namely p.

is called a binomial trial.